# Adding values from multiple inputs to the arraylist

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I' have a simple problem with adding values from inputs to the `ArrayList`.

I have a POJO like this:

```
public class Person {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private List<String> friends=new ArrayList<>();
    //getters and setters
```

then Backing bean:

```
  public class backingBean{
          Person p=new Person();

          public void addPerson(){

             for(String friend:p.getFriends)
                System.out.println(friend);
           }


}
```

and the view

```
        <h:form>
            <fieldset>
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">

                    <h:outputText value="Name" />
                    <h:inputText value="{backingBean.person.firstName}"/>              

                    <h:outputText value="LastName" />
                    <h:inputText value="#{backingBean.person.lastName}"/>


                    <h:outputText value="Friends" />
                    <h:inputText value="#{backingBean.person.friends}" />
                    <h:inputText value="#{backingBean.person.friends}" />

                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:commandButton  value="Add"
                    action="#{backingBean.addPerson}" />

            </fieldset>
        </h:form>
```

When I try to addPerson I get this error:

```
summary=(Conversion Error setting value...
```

I don't understand why convert String to String?

Comment: `Person` is a complex type, you'll need a converter. Besides that, what are your expectations for binding an input text to an arrayList?

Comment: is this for JSF 2 or JSF 1.2?

Comment: Is there any shortcut besides converter, because I need it just for simple test for adding values into arraylist

Comment: @extra90 **please** tell us if this is for JSF 1.2 or JSF 2.

Comment: @extra90 Is your requirement only to add two friends or more friends will be added later.

Comment: Sorry for late response. It is jsf 2. it can be added more then two friends.

Answer (score 2):

You can't bind `value` of `h:inputText` to `ArrayList` (without converter). When you submit form (by clicking button) JSF tries to call `setFriends(String)` and this is where this `Exception` occurs. Try to figure out what you are trying to achieve with these two `h:inputText` elements.

Comment: I'm trying to add friends names into arraylist. These inputs meant to be for adding into arraylist

Comment: The first part if your statement is technically incorrect. That was the reason behind converters.

Comment: I founded the solution. Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add 2 friends, just create only 2 different variables in backing bean as :

```
private String friend1;
private String friend2;
```

and then add them in addPerson like this:

```
    List<String> friends=new ArrayList<String>();
    friends.add(friend1);
    friends.add(friend2);

    p.setFriends(friends);
```

Not tested can be some bugs.

EDIT:

And if this not satisfies you, you can look at this @BalusC [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7257808/1692632)